# Multiple amp-selectors with state setting events

Tags: amp-html

I have two amp-selector elements on a page:

```
<amp-selector layout="container" on="select: AMP.setState({
      a1SelectedOption: event.targetOption
    })">
  <div option="a" selected>Option A</div>
  <div option="b">Option B</div>
</amp-selector>
<amp-selector layout="container" on="select: AMP.setState({
      a2SelectedOption: event.targetOption
    })">
  <div option="c" selected>Option C</div>
  <div option="d">Option D</div>
</amp-selector>
```

I then have text placeholders:

```
<h3 id="a1" [text]="a1SelectedOption">a</h3>
<h3 id="a2" [text]="a2SelectedOption">c</h3>
```

When someone first interacts with either selector the other placeholder gets triggered and updates the text to null e.g. after page load, select Option B, placeholders html becomes `<h3 id="a1" [text]="a1SelectedOption">b</h3> <h3 id="a2" [text]="a2SelectedOption">null</h3>`.

I suspect this is because both use `event.targetOption` in the `on` statement for each selector but the [docs on events](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#amp-selector) aren't clear for me as to how to resolve.

What is the appropriate way to set variable values that is independent of other amp-selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMP event model seems to trigger all the state values to assess so it flashes the other variable into creation with a null value.

To prevent this variables must be initialised with a default i.e.

```
<amp-state id="a1SelectedOption"><script type="application/json"> "a" </script></amp-state>
<amp-state id="a2SelectedOption"><script type="application/json"> "c" </script></amp-state>
```